# Reverse proxy for external URL - Apache

Tags: apache, reverse-proxy

I configured my apache so that it can forward my requests to external URL like google.com, but the reverse proxy doesn't work.

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
ServerName authtest.com
ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPreserveHost On
<Proxy *>
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from All
</Proxy>
<LocationMatch "/google">
  ProxyPass https://www.google.com/
  ProxyPassReverse https://www.google.com/
</LocationMatch>
</VirtualHost>
```

Is it possible for me to reverse proxy external websites?

Answer (score 3):

> Is it possible for me to reverse proxy external websites?

Yes but with significant downsides.

Note: when I tried your configuration, I got `SSL Proxy requested for [...] but not enabled [Hint: SSLProxyEngine]` in the logs so I added `SSLProxyEngine on`.

## Host issue

When you make a HTTP/1.1 request to a server, you automatically add the hostname in the request. When you proxy them, you have two possibilites:

```
[browser] --(Host: authtest.com)--> [apache proxy] --(Host: authtest.com)--> Google
```

or

```
[browser] --(Host: authtest.com)--> [apache proxy] --(Host: google.com)--> Google
```

The first one is what you get with `ProxyPreserveHost On`. Google servers won't handle requests for `authtest.com`, you should remove this line.

Even in the second case, you can have issues. `ProxyPassReverse` will handle redirects but only for the given domain: I'm in France, google.com redirects me to google.fr (a different domain) and the reverse proxy doesn't rewrite the redirect.

An other issue is the referer: if a service sees requests for images/css/js coming from a different web site it may consider it as bandwidth leeching and block them. Now, you need to rewrite the html of the response too ([mod_proxy_html](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy_html.html) will help but it's not a silver bullet).

## Path issue

In your example, you proxy <authtest>**/google** to <google>**/**. Like above, you need to rewrite the html: absolute links/resources won't work unless your server adds `/google` everywhere. Same for relative links/resources (but with more edge cases). If you owned the backend server, you could have checked urls in html/css/js files. Here, if the url is built dynamically in the browser using js you can't do anything.

If you can proxy `/` to `/` (or `/whatever` to `/whatever`) you will avoid a lot of issues here.

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed description. In my project Iam proxy passsing coupleof webistes using the same domain name i.e authTest but different locations like /google to google.com and /fb to facebook. So there is when I'm having issues.

Answer (score 2):

Chech this [GIT Repo](https://github.com/Ismail-AlJubbah/docker-apache2-reverse-proxy)
I forked a GIT Repo and customized it to work with scenario:

```
[browser] --(Host: google.local)--> [apache proxy] --(Host: google.nl)--> Google
```

The Apache config as follows:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName google.local
    SSLProxyEngine on
    ProxyRequests Off
    <Proxy *>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from All
    </Proxy>
        ProxyPass / https://www.google.nl/
        ProxyPassReverse / https://www.google.nl/

        ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/google.local-error.log
        CustomLog /var/log/apache2/google.local-access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. It didnt work in my case, as Iam looking for /google to google.